# Hologram project

Tags: arduino, hardware

I would like to do a project with an arduino that is a hologram screen. Is there a way to create a hologram project with an arduino? Is there any hologram hardware and can it be interfaced with an arduino?

Clarification on my question:
I got the idea from the scene in Prometheus where the engineer is working on his computer. I would like to recreate something similar. I would like to create a sort of planetarium with the arduino. I imagine something similar could be created with LED but wonder if a hologram could also be done. I've been doing some google searches and saw that there are holographic projectors.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "hologram screen"? The 3D things in _Star Wars_? That's not possible with current technology. Or are you talking about projecting stuff on a glass screen? Some pictures of what you want would be helpful here :)

Comment: It's [possible](http://www.avconcepts.com/holographic-projection/) but [non-trivial](http://river-valley.tv/large-viewing-angle-projection-type-electro-holography-using-mist-3d-screen/), and requires pretty powerful Digital Signal Processing, much more than is used in high end digital TV, and **well beyond the reach of current Arduino technology**. One could of course buy a holographic projector, nebulizer based or glass projection, and use an Arduino to push the buttons on it using servo motors.

Comment: @Manishearth They actually recreated the scene with Princess Leia in Star Wars, in real life :P

Comment: @Polar: Yep, I realized that now. I was thinking of a proper hologram projector, though. Not one which uses mists or glass panes.

Comment: Point for the OP - _If_ we could do something as sci-fi as this, then it would be logical for us to make a fortune out of it, patent and not share the method of doing it.

Comment: @Polar You would have to share it if you patented it... it goes on file for public display but you own the rights for 20 years... well after you pay the 10 grand in fees and filing. :)

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson I'm pretty certain it's 'share for a price' though, not something the OP could afford

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson Obtaining a patent doesn't need to be *10 grand* in fees and filing, going by personal experience :-) A lot of effort, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by [holographic screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holographic_screen) you mean projecting onto glass, then it's not possible with an Arduino. Arduinos don't have the processing power to drive a projector at a decent resolution. Something closer to a computer, like a Raspberry Pi, will work better here.

In regards to the construction of the screen, I think it's safe to say that's beyond the scope of this site.

Some Googling directed me to another project you might fine fun. An [Arduino Laser Projector](http://www.adafruit.com/blog/2010/07/07/arduino-laser-projector/).

Comment: That wouldn't work with what he said: *`@Polar: Yep, I realized that now. I was thinking of a proper hologram projector, though. Not one which uses mists or glass panes.`*. Good link, though.

Comment: Well the answer of "no, it's not immediately possible with an Arduino" still stands. ;)

Comment: @AnnonomusPerson: ... _I_ said that, and I'm not the OP.

Comment: @Manishearth Sorry: read that wrong. Oops. Sorry for the confusion again.